# CSV file contains trailing pipe delimiters

Tags: excel, csv, delimiter

I have an excel file and I exported the file into a pipe delimited csv file. However, in each row of the csv file, there are trailing pipes.

Here's a typical row:

```
dsad|asd|safd|sadaf|      |||||||||
ddss|sd|saadfdaf|dadf     |||||||||
```

Does anyone know how not to include those trailing pipes while exporting to csv from excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sheet you are exporting probably contains cell that excel believes has values in them (I call them ghost cells). To prevent this behaviour, I have two suggestions:

- Copy the spreadsheet to a fresh new spreasheet and export again. It should be fine.
- Delete all the columns after the last column containing data (Do not use the <kbd>Delete</kbd>/<kbd>Del</kbd> key, select the columns till the end and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> instead). After this, save the workbook then export again.

If those don't work, there's probably some rows with actual data somewhere, and there, the data will be correctly delimited by the pipes. Might be best to count the number of columns of data that you have and make sure your resulting csv file has the same number of columns.

If this still doesn't work... just shout I guess? ^^;